# mysql query to return record from one table vs list of values from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables author, book, author_book. I want a mysql query which will return me author, list of books and show output like this:

```
Author    |     Books
===========================
Author1   |    book1, book2, book3
Author2   |    book4
Author3   |    book5
```

**Updated::**

group_concat worked for me if i have author id in book table.

But if I have 3 tables(author, book, author_book) and I want to show book name then how it will work?

Comment: how tables are related ? what is the common key ?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: Ask a new question. You can link back to this one if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` is your friend, I think about this:

```
SELECT Author.Name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Books.Name SEPARATOR ', ' ORDER BY Books.Name) AS Books
FROM Author
INNER JOIN Author_Book ON Author.Id = Author_Book.AuthorId
INNER JOIN Book ON Author_Book.BookId = Book.Id
WHERE Author.Id=Books.AuthorId
GROUP BY Author.Name
ORDER BY Author.Name
```

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is no one's friend :-(

Comment: @Strawberry Why, what is happening? By me it works without any problem.

Comment: i dislike it because it strips the intelligence out of the returned data. I'd prefer simply to JSON encode the returned array (assuming that option was available)

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, you have absolutely right. Especially if the "Books" will be split-ted from php :-)

Comment: thanks it worked for me , but i have one more question which I have updated please check..